# What syntax error is in my php code ? please

Tags: php

Hey what is the syntax error in this php code...scratching head at end of project please

```
<?php echo str_replace("\", "", $objVehicleData->getPrice());>
```

Comment: you forgot to close the tag `?>`

Comment: replace "\" with "\\"

Comment: There is no need to end a PHP script with `?>`.

Comment: Damn. End of project mate. Sorry

Comment: @Quentin unless you have to write HTML markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be

```
<?php echo str_replace("\\", "", $objVehicleData->getPrice()); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `\` character starts an escape sequence. The `"` immediately following it is escaped so it doesn't end the string.

You need to escape the `\` character:

```
replace("\\", "", $
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape `\`, like:

```
<?php echo str_replace("\\", "", $objVehicleData->getPrice()); ?>
```